# Best way to open main app from main menu in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I started learning winforms recently and I want to make a main menu with a start button so that when I click on the button it shows the next screen (im having a hard time trying to phrase that correctly).
I've tried using

```
            frm2.Show();
            frm2.Left = this.Left;
            frm2.Top = this.Top;
            frm2.Size = this.Size;
            this.Hide();
```

but the problem is that when the second form opens there's a small animation of it opening and also a small animation of the main form closing so it doesnt look seamless. Maybe it's better to just re-arrange the layout of the form upon clicking the button? Whats the best implementation?

Comment: By "next screen" you mean another form? So you want to show the second form when a button is pressed in the first form. Is this correct? Please indicate if you want to open modally (blocking the first form like a dialog box does), side by side, or in place of the first form.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the behavior you want

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var next = new Form2();           // Create the next form
    next.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    next.Location = this.Location;    // Assign size/location
    next.Size = this.Size;
    this.Visible = false;             // Hide this form
    next.ShowDialog();                // Show next form, pausing this code here
    this.Visible = true;              // Resume code once next form is closed.
}
```

some screen-shots.

#### before click

[image: scr1]

#### after click

[image: scr2]